# How to load environment variables to ruby app spec using Rspec and .env

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm currently working on writing tests for a Ruby class. The class makes use of environment variables.

When I run the `spec` with `rspec spec/box_api.rb` I get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) BoxApi#client success Create Boxr::Client object
     Failure/Error: subject { BoxApi.new }

     KeyError:
       key not found: "BOX_USER_ID"
     # ./src/clients/box_api.rb:8:in `fetch'
     # ./src/clients/box_api.rb:8:in `initialize'
     # ./spec/box_api.rb:14:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It's not reading the environment variable.

I tried creating the `.env.test.local` file within spec folder without success. I'm using `dotenv` gem:

```
# Manage environment with .env file
gem 'dotenv', '~> 2.1.1'
```

How can I go about using the environment variables in test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your test helper file, you can add:

```
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load('.env.test.local')
```

This is on the [dotenv readme](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `dotenv` for this, you could stub `ENV` keys in your tests:

```
describe Foo do
  before do
    allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with('BOX_ID').and_return("1234")
  end

  it 'flips the environment variable value' do
    expect(subject.flip).to eq '4321'
  end
end
```

Or even stub the whole `ENV`:

```
describe Foo do
  let(:env) do
     { 'BOX_ID' => '1234' }
  end

  before do
    stub_const("ENV", env)
  end

  it 'flips the environment variable value' do
    expect(subject.flip).to eq '4321'
  end
end
```

I find this more reliable and easier to maintain than a separate file.